# Skype can’t be uninstalled completely on my PC?

Tags: skype, uninstall

I found that Skype couldn’t be uninstalled completely. Do you have the same problem? Do you solve it at last? I really want to remove Skype now…

Comment: when you say completely , what remains after you uninstall it ?

Comment: Do you mean to say you got a "Some elements could not be removed." type message after running the uninstaller?

Comment: What operating system? What version of Skype? How did you uninstall? Why do you think it wasn't uninstalled completely?

Answer (score 1):

- Go to Program Files and delete Skype folder in there.
- Go to My Computer --> 
  Your system drive (possibly C: ) 
  --> Documents and settings\Your Windows Username\Application data\
  delete Skype folder in there.
- Open Windows' "Start" menu and select "Run".
- Enter "regedit" in the text box and click "OK".
- Open the "Edit" drop-down menu and click "Find".
- Search for the keyword "Skype". Delete all search results.

Download RegSeeker (freeware)

- Install  Go to "Search" in Regseeker
- Type "Skype"  delete ALL entries
- regseeker finds.

Answer (score 1):

When applications are installed on Windows:

- they put their files in their folder. i.e. `C:\Program Files\Skype`
- they add *.dll files in the `Windows` diectoty
- they add values & keys to Windows registry (which can be accessed by regedit)
- they may add files in common Windows directories

I found an easier way than hunting down these installed items. A good application would be programmed to collect all those installed items and remove all of them when you want to uninstall.

This easier way (for me) is Revo Uninstaller. This application is very easy to use.

It is available to download for a free 30-day trial at http://www.revouninstaller.com/

I hope this will get your issue fixed.